# CORS issue while using Axios react pagination - pre-flight not allowed in OPTIONS request

Tags: nginx, axios, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a ec2 machine which is in private subnet running Gunicorn + nginx as a proxy and also this machine is behind an ALB where ALB is handling https and directing it to nginx which is using gunicorn as upstream server

Here is my nginx configuration.

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/www/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen    [::]:80;
    server_name testing.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /static/ {
      root /var/www/static/;
    }
    
    location @proxy_to_app {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' ;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        return 204; break;
        }

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;

    }
  }
```

Now I got a endpoint like https://testing.com which is used in my frontend application to call the APIs from the react using axios.

This application is using pagination and have headers and methods which is enabling CORS OPTIONS request from browser.

The response from the nginx for OPTION request is 204 and that is fine and the get request for the first page is success and I am getting the response as mentioned below

https://testing.com/v2/mycontent/mybooks?view=myview&language=&page_no=1

and the response header is showing the scheme is https only.

Now comes the another get request which is calling the page_no=2 which should be like this

https://testing.com/v2/mycontent/mybooks?view=myview&language=&page_no=2

but the scheme instead of https is http

http://testing.com/v2/mycontent/mybooks?view=myview&language=&page_no=2

I think due to which i getting this error
**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.**

I am not able to figure out what is making the scheme changing from https to http.

I tried to change the nginx configuration and now the nginx configuration is like allow every origin and all the headers. So to me its does't seeems like a nginx issue. I am not sure if this is a axios middle ware issue or i am missing something.

Following multiple answer from stackoverflow i implemented multiple things like removed credentials to false but still it doesn't work.